# How to typeset a list of specifications?

Tags: lists

I need to make a list of technical specifications like this:

[image: example of list of specifications]

It looks like description but I would like to have numbers flushed right like in my example, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1Here is an idea; getting left alignment of both columns is easier with `tabular` & friends than with `description`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\cheval}{ch}                                                 
\DeclareSIUnit{\tour}{tr}                                                 

\newcommand\myheading[1]{\hspace{-1em}\textbf{#1}\\}

\begin{document} 
  {
    \itshape La moto que nous allons analyser est une Suzuki GSX-R750
    dont les caract\'{e}ristiques principales sont reprises ci-dessous:\\[1em]
  }
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{>{\hspace{1em}}l l}
    Masse                     & \SI{163}{\kilo\gram}                                        \\
    Empattement               & \SI{1350}{\milli\meter}                                     \\
    Longueur                  & \SI{2040}{\milli\meter}                                     \\
    Hauteur de selle          & \SI{810}{\milli\meter}                                      \\
    Garde au sol              & \SI{130}{\milli\meter}                                      \\
    \myheading{Moteur}
    Puissance                 & \SI{106}{\cheval} \SI{12500}{\tour\per\minute}             \\
    Couple                    & \SI{7.42}{\meter\kilo\gram} \`a \SI{9500}{\tour\per\minute} \\
    \myheading{Suspension}
    Raideur avant             & \SI{10}{\kilo\newton\per\meter}                             \\
    Amortissement avant       & \SI{1}{\kilo\newton\second\per\meter}                       \\
    Raideur arri\`{e}re       & \SI{15}{\kilo\newton\per\meter}                             \\
    Amortissement arri\`{e}re & \SI{2}{\kilo\newton\second\per\meter}                       \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: if you're going to use a `tabular` then `siunitx` would almost certainly be mandatory here...

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, sorry. I'm completely new to `siunitx`.

Comment: no problem- I edited your example- one of the reasons to use `siunitx` is so that you can type the units in a way that makes sense; for example `\kilo\newton\per\meter`. I wasn't sure what `ch` and `tr` represent, but presumably someone will :) feel free to role back if you disagree

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely going to look into the `siunitx` manual after this. By the way, "tr" stands for "tour", the French term for "rotation".

Comment: ah, in which case you might like to use `\DeclareSIUnit{\tour}{tr}` and then change all `\tr` to `\tour`. Similarly if you find what `ch` stands for, you should change that too :)

Comment: "ch" stands for "cheval-vapeur", the French term for "horsepower".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8705/discussion-between-cmhughes-and-jubobs)

Answer (score 1):

You might use `\hfill` or `\dotfill`, (Lamport, p96)

```
\begin{itemize}
\item{Engine \hfill \$1000.00}
\item{Clutch \hfill \$400.00}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: A small note: the braces around the item text isn't necessary, as `\item` isn't a command that takes a mandatory argument. You can do just `\item Engine\hfill\$1000.00`.